# Hard deleted records visibility

Tags: delete

We are working on a process where we would like to permanently delete the records so that they are not visible even with workbench. We tried with hard delete but records are still visible for some period of time.

1. How long records will be kept after a hard delete operation? Is there a way we can change this setting?
2. Is there a solution where we can remove the records so that they are not visible? We are looking for some configuration or solution that makes records disappear from the system from viewers after a hard delete operation.
3. It seems like there is batch purging operation that needs to happen for the record to be completely deleted. How to set up this batch purging?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure someone will answer to all the questions, but I had a similar question few days back. So posting what I come to know;

Salesforce says,

[image]

in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_emptyrecyclebin.htm)

And I found this from the Rachit's [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/114053/22234)